# QGraphicsScene : get the QGraphicsItemGroup under the cursor

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I'm having trouble getting a pointer of a QGraphicsItemGroup bellow my cursor. `QGraphicsScene::ItemAt` return one of the objects of the group but the not ItemGroup it self.

Any clue how to do it ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `QGraphicsItem::group()` on the QGraphicsItem returned by `QGraphicsScene::itemAt()`.